# Which event can I use to trigger an update to a label before the click event is triggered by hitting enter on the keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, button, click

I have an application that does some pretty complicated calculations when a button is clicked.   I'm still trying to get this code more efficient but in the meantime I want to give the user feedback to show that the button has been clicked and the calculations are in progress by updating a label on the UI.

The UI is not updated until the click event has been completed so I have to put the code into an event that is called just before the click event's code is triggered.

So far I'm using the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event which is called before the click event is executed to update the label.  This works for a mouse click.
 BUT if the user hits Enter while the button is in focus it appears as though the `PreviewKeyDown` AND `KeyDown` events are never triggered, or at least not triggered before the Click event is triggered.

What event can I use to update the label when the enter key is hit OR do you know of another way I can get the label to update before the Click Event's Code is run?

Update: I've noticed that the `PreviewKeyDown` event is triggered before the `click` event, but I don't see the label updating before the `click` event code is run.  I don't see anything wrong with my code.

```
    private void Button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                lblMessage.Content = "Loading...";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: bind a string variable with label. Make the binding with label 2 way. Update the text when user clicks on the button. It might refersh the label as the binding is two way.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I'm going to give that a try.  I'll report back if it works.

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer if any posted answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your dilemma, I sounds as though you're tying up your user interface thread with the business logic. A more effective solution would be to create a new thread and run your calculations there.  You create your calculation class, subscribe to a completed event in the executing code and start the thread.  This way you can set the label at any point during the execution as your business logic is operating on a separate thread from your user interface.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  I'm going to look into that, I can see in my mind how it works, just haven't coded something like that before.  Don't tell me how yet - I want the challenge of figuring that part out for myself.

Comment: Good, because it's been awhile since I've done anything like it!  Let me know though, I can always do a little research and try to provide an example.  I think the trickiest piece will be subscribing to an event on a separate thread.

Comment: +1 threading the process has the advantage of not freezing your interface.

Comment: Don't click the following link before you're done challenging yourself ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773448/c-sharp-run-process-without-freezing-my-apps-gui

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the Command Property of the Button instead of the events?

The Command is triggerd by mouse click or enter key.

[Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

[CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx)

Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding CalculationCommand}" Content=" Calculate" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding StateText}" />
    </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _stateText;

    public RelayCommand CalculationCommand { get; set; }

    public string StateText
    {
        get { return _stateText; }
        set { _stateText = value;  OnPropertyChanged("StateText");}
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CalculationCommand = new RelayCommand(OnCalculate);
        StateText = string.Empty;
    }

    private void OnCalculate(object obj)
    {
        StateText = "Please wait, calculating.";

        var context = TaskScheduler.Current;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
                                        //Calculating Logic goes here   
                                   }).ContinueWith(x =>
                                                       {
                                                           StateText = "Done.";
                                                       },context);


    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I am using the RelayCommand from Josh Smith [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thank you, this would work ideally, but one problem... I'm working on legacy code that I didn't write and it is not using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) to force the label to update after you edit it.  Then you don't need to worry about tying in a different event - just change whatever you need to, call `.Refresh()`, then start the major processing.