# Starting to use threads

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my head around threads, in my current application threads would be the best way to deal with it, what i have:

```
    public void threadsTest() {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
        // loop over the listview getting the first value
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewBacklinks.Items)
        {
            // try...
            try
            {
                var mainURL = item.Text;
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var pageHtml = wc.DownloadString(mainURL);
                        if (pageHtml.Contains(Text))
                        {
                            var subitems = item.SubItems.Add("<a href=\"" + item.SubItems[1].Text + "\">anchor text</a>");
                            item.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception)
                    {
                        item.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                        //Helpers.returnMessage("Work done!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                Helpers.returnMessage(ex.ToString());
            }
        }}));
    }

    private void btnAnalyzeAnchorText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // attempting threads
        var t = new Thread(threadsTest);
        t.Start();
    }
```

I thought like the backgroundWorker it would not freeze up the GUI but it did so i put in the invoke to access GUI elements, i don't think it looks right, the way it is now the GUI is still unresponsive until the work is done, i have viewed some tutorials but it's not totally sinking in, any help/tips on cracking threads would be great.

Comment: `Invoke()` runs the given code on the UI thread, so it's no wonder that your UI is blocked. Invoke/BeginInvoke only the smallest portion of the code you can (i.e. setting the BackColor here). If your list is too large, you could still run into issues with updating the UI too often. I'd suggest looking into async/await as it would be a more elegant way of doing what you're attempting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# run process without freezing my App's GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773448/c-sharp-run-process-without-freezing-my-apps-gui)

Comment: A WebClient is a GUI element so your application simply is not well suited for threading...

Comment: Once removing the invoke i do indeed get the cross thread error, how do i get the gui values without invoking? thanks for the help guys

Comment: so i am better just using a background worker really?

Comment: No. You're better structuring your code so that you don't mix UI interaction with the business of fetching data with a WebClient. You're better off not thinking in terms of threads, but rather, in terms of asynchronous IO (using async/await).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
public void threadsTest(string[] urls)
{
    var results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string mainURL in urls)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var pageHtml = wc.DownloadString(mainURL);
            results[mainUrl] = pageHtml;
        }
    }
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => ProcessResults(results)));
}
```

There are no UI elements in this code, just the heavy lifting of the `WebClient`.

Then in the new `ProcessResults` you're back on the UI thread so then you can set your results.

The call to the thread needs to pass through an array of urls (strings) but you get that before creating the thread so you're still in the UI thread and thus it is safe to do.